# Shared onedrive folder with office365 group but office365 user can't see folder in "shared with me" option

Tags: office-365-groups, onedrive

I have created a group in office365 and added member in that group and then I created a folder in OneDrive and after that, I am sharing that folder with the office365 group which I just created.

But when I log in to OneDrive with the user which is already available into that group and navigate to "shared with me" option, but I am unable to see that shared folder there.

I am doing the above task using Microsoft graph API.

Please help me to find the above solution.